# Leitura tabela em Python com Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Estou precisando pegar uma tabela do portal da transparência para depois gravar no banco de dados. Estou usando o Beautiful Soup.

Não consigo trazer no `request` a parte que tem os dados e por consequência nenhuma tag que procuro funciona.

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get('http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/despesas/favorecido?paginacaoSimples=true&tamanhoPagina=&offset=&direcaoOrdenacao=asc&colunasSelecionadas=data%2CdocumentoResumido%2ClocalizadorGasto%2Cfase%2Cespecie%2Cfavorecido%2CufFavorecido%2Cvalor%2Cug%2Cuo%2Corgao%2CorgaoSuperior%2Cgrupo%2Celemento%2Cmodalidade&de=20%2F03%2F2019&ate=20%2F03%2F2019&faseDespesa=1&ordenarPor=fase&direcao=asc').text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

Tabela = soup.find('table',{'class':'dataTable no-footer'})
```

Não vem nada. No primeiro `print` já não vem a tabela com os dados.

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado? Primeira vez que faço *Scraping*.

Comment: A tabela não é preenchida pelo servidor ao carregar a página, ela é preenchida por AJAX pelo javascript. Se você acessar [a url onde o ajax pega estas informações](http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/despesas/favorecido/resultado?paginacaoSimples=true&tamanhoPagina=15&offset=0&direcaoOrdenacao=asc&colunaOrdenacao=fase&colunasSelecionadas=data,documentoResumido,localizadorGasto,fase,especie,favorecido,ufFavorecido,valor,ug,uo,orgao,orgaoSuperior,grupo,elemento,modalidade&de=20/03/2019&ate=20/03/2019&faseDespesa=1&_=1553284143535) é mais fácil e já vem em JSON pronto para usar os dados.

Comment: Sem contar que se pegar o JSON não é preciso usar BeautifulSoup, basta usar `json.loads` que os dados estarão prontos.

Comment: Excelente dica Fernando. Vou mudar o foco e trabalhar no JSON. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Agora minha guerra é para tranformar esse Json em eu Dataframe com o Pandas. Não sei se tenho que fazer alguma normalização ou conversão porque ele não reconhece a estrutura. Preciso salvar em arquivo primeiro?

Comment: Antes dos dados tem a quantidade registros:{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":9223372036854775807,"recordsFiltered":9223372036854775807,"data":[{"data":"21/03/2019","documento":"110001000012019NE000237". No resultado sai na frente dos dados que ficam todos em uma coluna.